# Bigquery cancel or stop a batch query job which is not started yet (Status.State = "PENDING")

Tags: google-bigquery

If for some reason it is wanted to stop/cancel a batch query job that is not started yet (Status.State = "PENDING"), is it possible to do it?
(library used: net Google.Apis.Bigquery.v2.1.5.0.122-beta).

Answer (score 5):

BigQuery now supports canceling query jobs. You can do this via the `bq` command line client via:

```
bq cancel <job_id>
```

or from the API via the jobs.cancel method (documented [here](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/v2/jobs/cancel))

Comment: I agree. It can be quite frustrating if you realize you made a mistake after the job started. I made a mistake in the `table_date_range()`, which lead to a unnecessarily long and slow job.

Comment: Updated to indicate that this is now supported.