# Google BigQuery: Stop running query

Tags: google-bigquery

I have run a query on Google BigQuery several hours ago, and the query is still running. I clicked "abandon", but it appears there is no way to stop a query. What can I do? Can I contact Google somehow, so they stop the query?

I've been working on a project for a company which analyzes Google Analytics data with BigQuery, so I don't want to run them a big bill or something.
(Maybe StackOverflow is not the right place to ask this question, but I've tried to find another place, and I couldn't. On the BigQuery support page, it is said that questions should be asked here, with the google-bigquery tag, so I'm doing that).

I've written a query (which I don't want to paste or describe here, as someone might abuse it to block BigQuery or something, I don't know). Let's just say it includes inner joins. After I've written it, and before running it, the console message was something like "This will analyze 674KB of data", which looked OK, given the fact that the table only has 10,000 rows. I've got the same message after clicking on "abandon" query, something like "You can abandon this, but you will still be billed for 674KB of data".

I try very hard to make sure what I do doesn't cause problems to someone, so I've actually run that query on a local PostgreSQL database (with the exact same data - 10,000 rows) as in BigQuery, and the query there finishes in a second or two.

How can I cancel this query, and can I (the company I've worked for) be billed for something more than 674KB of data?

Comment: Don't worry about the cost: regardless of how long it takes, you'll be either charged for those 674KB - or nothing, if the query fails. If you copy paste the job id for the query, the support team might be able to debug said query too. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

At the time being, there is no way to stop a BigQuery job once it's started, neither via web interface or API calls.

According to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19497655/bigquery-cancel-or-stop-a-batch-query-job-which-is-not-started-yet-status-state), this feature may be added in the future.

As BigQuery will shard the query to multiple machines, even a large query (TeraByte level) will not have a large impact on an individual machine, let alone a query of 674KB. However, according to [this](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/pricing), [this](http://www.wolframalpha.com/share/clip?f=d41d8cd98f00b204e9800998ecf8427e24v646kg5g) is the amount that you will be charged.

Here are some tips to save money in BigQuery.

First thing to know is that, unlike traditional RDBMS, BigQuery is column based, and you will be charged by the amount of data in the columns rather than in the rows.

- That means, don't include columns that you do not need in the query. This may sound trivial, but sometimes people coming from RDBMS may write queries like this:

  ```
  SELECT
      COUNT(*), user_id
  FROM
      [Dataset.Table]
  ```

  The query is absolutely correct, but instead of being charged only the size of user_id column, Google would actually bill the whole table for this query. Therefore it's a good idea to explicitly specify the column names.
- Break the tables into smaller chunks. Instead of having a single table that contains all the data, it's a good idea to split the table according to date, and use [table wildcard functions](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/query-reference#tablewildcardfunctions) to stitch the tables together during query. In this case, you won't be billed by rows that you don't need.

Answer (score 1):

BigQuery supports canceling query jobs. 
You can do this via the `bq` command line utility:

```
bq cancel <job_id>
```

or from the API via the jobs.cancel method (documented [here](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/v2/jobs/cancel))